# Programmatically change Sharepoint Online subsite URL

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I have done a lot of researching and haven't been able to find a solution to this.  Does anyone know how to programmatically change the URL of a subsite on Sharepoint Online using CSOM?  Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: imho it's not possible directly when you want to use csom only. Referring to http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/dn268594%28v=office.15%29.aspx you have no access to SPContext in csom, which denies the method described here which I think is the only one possible: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5069b7b1-b6ac-4888-a7b4-49835f0f99f0/change-wss-30-subsite-url-programmatically. But it might be possible to write a webservice, call ChangeName on serverside and return new name to work with it via ajax, when this is an option..?

Comment: Thanks Dominik - I was thinking the same thing but was able to complete it using the csom.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

I finally was able to figure out how to do this.  Apparently all that was needed was to update the ServerRelativeUrl property on the ClientContext.Web.  Here is the code for anyone else who may need to do something similar:

```
using (ClientContext context = this.GetContext(this.siteUrl))
        {
            var web = context.Web;
            context.Load(web);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            web.ServerRelativeUrl = "/sites/SiteCollection/NewSiteName";
            web.Update();
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
```